# Scala XML Extracting

Tags: xml, scala

I have the following XML structure.

```
val elem = 
<persons>
  <gender>M</gender>
  <person>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <age>30</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>San</name>
    <age>32</age>
  </person>
</persons>
<persons>
  <gender>F</gender>
  <person>
    <name>Joan</name>
    <age>30</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Julia</name>
    <age>32</age>
  </person>
</persons>
```

How can I extract all Persons based on the gender attribute?

Comment: You should refrain from using the built-in xml literals... They're being removed from the language and won't be supported at all in the future

Comment: @Electic Coffee You have a source for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured that out. Here is what I did:

```
(elem \\ "persons").filter(x => (x \\ "gender" text) == "M")
```